# Calculating the induced map on homology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to figure out how to define explicitly a orientation reversing map on $\mathbb{C}P^1$, which exists because we have the antipodal map on $S^2$. I've thought of various homeomorphisms which could provide this orientation reversing map, but I can't think of way how to decide whether the map induces the identity or the orientation reversing map. Note that I'm considering the induced map on $H^2(\mathbb{C}P^1;\mathbb{Z})$.

One example of such a map is just transposing the elements, that is, we map $[z_0:z_1]$ to $[z_1:z_0]$. Another possibility is to use conjugation, that is, we map $[z_0:z_1]$ to $[\bar{z_0}:\bar{z_1}]$. What is the right way to approach the calculation of the induced maps on homology?

Any help is welcome!

Comment: You could use that $\mathbb CP^1$ is the one-point compactification of $\mathbb C$, and then just use the map $z \mapsto \bar z$ on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: In what way can this be applied?

Comment: Well, the function $z \mapsto \bar z$ is obviously orientation reversing on $\mathbb C$ itself. And since $\mathbb CP^1 = \mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$ and $\mathbb C = \mathbb CP^1 - \{\infty\}$, it follows that the extension of the function $z \mapsto \bar z$ to all of $\mathbb CP^1$ (by taking $\infty$ to $\infty$) is also orientation reversing.

Comment: You can, by the way, understand this "one point compactification" in terms of homogeneous coordinates: the inclusion map $\mathbb C \hookrightarrow \mathbb CP^1$ is defined by $z \mapsto [z:1]$, and the image of this map is $\mathbb CP^1 - \{[1:0]\}$, so in my earlier notation you can identify $\infty = [1:0]$.

Comment: So, in homogeneous coordinates, this orientation reversing map is defined by $[z:1] \mapsto [\bar z:1]$ and $[1:0] \mapsto [1:0]$.

Comment: By the way, the map $[z_0:z_1] \mapsto [z_1:z_0]$ is not orientation reversing: this is equivalent to $[z:1] \mapsto [1:z]=[1/z:1]$, and the map $z \mapsto 1/z$ preserves orientation.